# Filter Google Maps autocomplete to Barcelona, Spain

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to filter results, to Barcelona, Spain not to Spain as is seen in code.

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
       (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {
            types: ['geocode'],
            componentRestrictions: {
                country: 'es',
            }
        });
```

I tried with **postalCode** using 08 (Barcelona prefix) and 08000 inside **componentRestrictions** and does not work.

There is away I can filter only to Barcelona address in autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set bounds like as below:

```
var cityBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

var options = {
  bounds: cityBounds,
  types: ['geocode'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'es'}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I check and bounds give preference to results contained on the area but display results outside bounds anyway. :(

Comment: you could do this -`var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input); autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);` - check this out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict bounds with the option: `strictBounds: true`. like this:

```
var options = {
  bounds: cityBounds,
  types: ['geocode'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'es'},
  strictBounds: true
};
```